# Android sdkmanager gives IllegalArgumentException for any argument

Tags: android, docker, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I installed, inside docker, android SDK. No matter what arguments I pass to the SDK, I get the same error about illegal arguments. Example:

```
RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --version
```

or

```
RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28"
```

I get

```
Warning: Could not create settings
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.<init>(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:428)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:152)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:134)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:57)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Usage:
  sdkmanager [--uninstall] [<common args>] [--package_file=<file>] [<packages>...]
  sdkmanager --update [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --list [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --licenses [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --version

With --install (optional), installs or updates packages.
    By default, the listed packages are installed or (if already installed)
    updated to the latest version.
With --uninstall, uninstall the listed packages.

    <package> is a sdk-style path (e.g. "build-tools;23.0.0" or
             "platforms;android-23").
    <package-file> is a text file where each line is a sdk-style path
                   of a package to install or uninstall.
    Multiple --package_file arguments may be specified in combination
    with explicit paths.

With --update, all installed packages are updated to the latest version.

With --list, all installed and available packages are printed out.

With --licenses, show and offer the option to accept licenses for all
     available packages that have not already been accepted.

With --version, prints the current version of sdkmanager.

Common Arguments:
    --sdk_root=<sdkRootPath>: Use the specified SDK root instead of the SDK
                              containing this tool

    --channel=<channelId>: Include packages in channels up to <channelId>.
                           Common channels are:
                           0 (Stable), 1 (Beta), 2 (Dev), and 3 (Canary).

    --include_obsolete: With --list, show obsolete packages in the
                        package listing. With --update, update obsolete
                        packages as well as non-obsolete.

    --no_https: Force all connections to use http rather than https.

    --proxy=<http | socks>: Connect via a proxy of the given type.

    --proxy_host=<IP or DNS address>: IP or DNS address of the proxy to use.

    --proxy_port=<port #>: Proxy port to connect to.

    --verbose: Enable verbose output.

* If the env var REPO_OS_OVERRIDE is set to "windows",
  "macosx", or "linux", packages will be downloaded for that OS.
```

What could be causing this? I followed this: https://hub.docker.com/r/chibatching/docker-android-sdk/dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction.

It happened to me for Linux. I used `--sdk_root` and it worked.

Ex:
If the tools are installed in `$ANDROID_HOME`, and tools are located in
`$ANDROID_HOME/tools`, I have to use this option  `--sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME`.

Then run

`$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list --sdkroot=$ANDROID_HOME`